# std::unordered_set insert get the object

Tags: c++, c++11

I am inserting an object in an unordered_set.
I want to get the actual object copy from within the set after/if it is inserted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

int main ( void )
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> sentence;

    auto res = sentence.insert( "alex" );
    if ( res.second )
        std::cout <<  *res.first <<  std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above simple example, works fine. 
When I try it with my custom class:

```
std::unordered_set<Policy> _policies;
...
...
if ( std::shared_ptr<Policy> policy = calculatePolicy ( state, action, 0.f ) )
{
    auto res = _policies.insert ( *policy );
    if ( res.second )
        return std::make_shared<Policy>( *res.first );
```

I get:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator<Policy, true, true>’ to ‘const Policy&’
```

Why am I getting an std::_detail::_Node_const_iterator isntead of a const MyClass&?

How do I get the reference to the object that was just inserted?

Comment: Add your set declaration for the `_policies` var to the posted question code. Its important. I've a feeling if you're not storing `std::shared_ptr<Policy>` in your set, you should be. (and it doesn't look like you are).

Comment: Yes R Sahu, sorry, typo

Comment: @WhozCraig no, I wasn't I was using Policy objects. I've changed it to std::unordered_set<std::shared<Policy>> and I don't get compilation errors. Thank you, care to elaborate why this happened?

Comment: If your set is really `std::unordered_set<Policy>` then your code should compile. [Mine does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/880fdfccfa00334b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The members of an `unordered_set` are required to be `const` so that their hash doesn't change - this would break the underlying data structures. The iterator enforces `const` in the type of the `first` element.

Comment: So, basically I can't have access to the inserted object, in order to avoid breaking const'ness?

Comment: @Alex you can have access, but it must be `const` access. You can examine the object any way you'd like, but no changes are allowed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

To fix the compiler errors, change the line

```
    return std::make_shared<Policy>( *res.first );
```

to

```
    return std::make_shared<Policy>( *(*res.first) );
```

`*res.first` is the `shared_ptr`. `*(*res.first)` is a reference to the underlying `Policy` object.